# NgIf - Table rows are not being displayed when model is updated

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

Objective: I am trying to create a table with hierarchy structure. When the button inside td is clicked, it will set isAnimalDisplay property to true and those rows should appear.

Issue: When button is clicked, model get updated and sets isAnimalDisplay to true for all elements in sub_animal array. However, the rows are not showing up.

**tree.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TreeComponent } from './tree.component';

describe('TreeComponent', () => {
  let component: TreeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TreeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TreeComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TreeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**tree.component.html**

```
<table border="1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="min-width: 200px; text-align: center;">Code</th>
      <th style="min-width: 300px; text-align: center">Name</th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>              
<ng-container *ngFor="let asset of asset.sub_animals"  >
  <tr *ngIf="asset.isAnimalDisplay"  style="height:30px;"  >
    <td class="align-middle"  style="text-align: left;"> 
      <button style="margin:3px" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" *ngIf="asset.isAnimalDisplay"  (click)='toggleSubAssetRows(asset)'> + </button>
      <button style="margin:3px" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" *ngIf="asset.isAnimalDisplay == false"  (click)='toggleSubAssetRows(asset)'> - </button>
      &nbsp; <b>{{asset.animalCode}}</b> 
    </td>
    <td class="align-middle" style="text-align: center">{{asset.animalName}}</td>    
  </tr>    
</ng-container>
</tbody>     

</table>
```

**tree.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree',
  templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css']
})
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() asset: AnimalsModel;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.asset));
  }

  toggleSubAssetRows(asset: AnimalsModel) {        
    if (asset.sub_animals) { 
      console.log("here");
      asset.sub_animals.forEach(n => n.isAnimalDisplay ? this.collapseSubAssetRows(n) : n.isAnimalDisplay = true);
      asset.sub_animals.forEach(n => console.log(n.animalName + '  ' + n.isAnimalDisplay));
    }
  }

  collapseSubAssetRows(asset: AnimalsModel) {    
    asset.isAnimalDisplay = false;    
    if (asset.sub_animals) {      
      asset.sub_animals.forEach(n => this.collapseSubAssetRows(n));
    }
  }
}
```

Following provides sample data, you can ignore if not reproducing:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimalsModel } from '../app/tree/models/animals.model'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  rootAnimals: AnimalsModel = new AnimalsModel();

  ngOnInit(){
    let  animals = new AnimalsModel();
    animals.animalCode = "AN"
    animals.animalName = "Animals"

    let  reptlle = new AnimalsModel();
    reptlle.animalName = "Raptlle"
    reptlle.animalCode = "RPAN"

    let lizard = new AnimalsModel();
    lizard.animalName = "Lizard"
    lizard.animalCode = "LZRPAN"

    let snake = new AnimalsModel();
    snake.animalName = "Snake"
    snake.animalCode = "SNRPAN"

    let bird = new AnimalsModel();
    bird.animalName = "Bird"
    bird.animalCode = "BRRPAN"

    let salamander = new AnimalsModel();
    salamander.animalName = "Salamandar"
    salamander.animalCode = "SLMDLZRPAN"

    let canary = new AnimalsModel();
    canary.animalName = "Canary"
    canary.animalCode = "CMBRRPAN"

    let tweetle = new AnimalsModel();
    tweetle.animalName = "Tweetle"
    tweetle.animalCode = "TWBRRPAN"

    let mammal = new AnimalsModel();    
    mammal.animalName = "Mammal"
    mammal.animalCode = "MMAN"

    let equine = new AnimalsModel();
    equine.animalName = "Equine"
    equine.animalCode = "EQMMAN"

    let bovine = new AnimalsModel();
    bovine.animalName = "Bovine"
    bovine.animalCode = "BVMMAN"

    mammal.sub_animals.push(equine);
    mammal.sub_animals.push(bovine);
    canary.sub_animals.push(tweetle)
    bird.sub_animals.push(canary);
    lizard.sub_animals.push(salamander);
    reptlle.sub_animals.push(lizard);
    reptlle.sub_animals.push(snake);
    reptlle.sub_animals.push(bird);
    animals.sub_animals.push(reptlle);
    animals.sub_animals.push(mammal);

    this.rootAnimals = animals;
    this.rootAnimals.sub_animals.forEach(n => n.isAnimalDisplay = true);
  }


}

Following provides sample data:
**app.componenet.ts**

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AnimalsModel } from '../app/tree/models/animals.model'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

      rootAnimals: AnimalsModel = new AnimalsModel();

      ngOnInit(){
        let  animals = new AnimalsModel();
        animals.animalCode = "AN"
        animals.animalName = "Animals"

        let  reptlle = new AnimalsModel();
        reptlle.animalName = "Raptlle"
        reptlle.animalCode = "RPAN"

        let lizard = new AnimalsModel();
        lizard.animalName = "Lizard"
        lizard.animalCode = "LZRPAN"

        let snake = new AnimalsModel();
        snake.animalName = "Snake"
        snake.animalCode = "SNRPAN"

        let bird = new AnimalsModel();
        bird.animalName = "Bird"
        bird.animalCode = "BRRPAN"

        let salamander = new AnimalsModel();
        salamander.animalName = "Salamandar"
        salamander.animalCode = "SLMDLZRPAN"

        let canary = new AnimalsModel();
        canary.animalName = "Canary"
        canary.animalCode = "CMBRRPAN"

        let tweetle = new AnimalsModel();
        tweetle.animalName = "Tweetle"
        tweetle.animalCode = "TWBRRPAN"

        let mammal = new AnimalsModel();    
        mammal.animalName = "Mammal"
        mammal.animalCode = "MMAN"

        let equine = new AnimalsModel();
        equine.animalName = "Equine"
        equine.animalCode = "EQMMAN"

        let bovine = new AnimalsModel();
        bovine.animalName = "Bovine"
        bovine.animalCode = "BVMMAN"

        mammal.sub_animals.push(equine);
        mammal.sub_animals.push(bovine);
        canary.sub_animals.push(tweetle)
        bird.sub_animals.push(canary);
        lizard.sub_animals.push(salamander);
        reptlle.sub_animals.push(lizard);
        reptlle.sub_animals.push(snake);
        reptlle.sub_animals.push(bird);
        animals.sub_animals.push(reptlle);
        animals.sub_animals.push(mammal);

        this.rootAnimals = animals;
        this.rootAnimals.sub_animals.forEach(n => n.isAnimalDisplay = true);
      }


    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've implemented the following method:
toggleSubAssetRows(asset)

Comment: Assuming you want to just toggle that row on or off I would do this in the click instead of calling a method:

(click)='asset.isAnimalDisplay = !asset.isAnimalDisplay'

Comment: @TrystanHumann I have added the tree.component.ts which has implementation of method: toggleSubAssetRows(asset). The reason I am calling a method for toggle is, I need to set isAnimalDisplay = true for all child elements.

Comment: What errors are your console giving you?

Comment: No errors in console. It prints values being toggle when button click but new rows does not appear.

Comment: It sounds like its losing access to the value changed since you are passing the value to another component. Look into how outputs work or move the method to your AppComponent. Link: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter